# Algorithm for Probabilities in a "Random" Integers Runs test

Tags: statistics, random-number-generation, probability

Suppose you have a set of N random integers. ( aka bytes 0..255 )

You then consider each subsequent neighbor as "ascending" or "descending", counting the number of consecutive neighbors who are also of the same kind. ( i.e. 1234 is a "run" of 3 ascending neighbors; 123431 is a ascending run of 3 followed by a descending run of 2 ).  As an assumption, the problem considers both ascending and descending to be functionally symmetrical/same.  We can only consider runs of one direction.

In the set of N members, what is the probability of any Run of length L?   Such that one could test a series of bytes generated by a PRNG and gauge how closely the series is "Random" by how well its Runs fit the theorethical model.  ( This is only one test, and with the usual disclaimers about "determining randomness" in place. )

i.e.  In the set of N, how many runs of length 1 should there be?   Is there a formula for Runs-of-Length given N ( and the range of values of bytes ) ?

I feel that there should be a "simple" formula/algorithm, but I cannot figure it out and I have not found any similar information with searches.

Other similar tests with Runs use empirical results from a "golden" PRNG, but I feel that is unwise and really just testing similarity to some other PRNG ( which may have a serious unknown flaw/bias ).

An EXAMPLE data set, a specific series generated the following "rising" runs.

$N$ = $67108864$

```
[Length]=   num of occurs
[0]=    0
[1]=    13926757
[2]=    6144339
[3]=    1779212
[4]=    391946
[5]=    71071
[6]=    10716
[7]=    1390
[8]=    164
[9]=    16
[10]=   3
[11]=   0
[12]=   0
```

Total number of Runs = $22325614$

As you can see, the distribution appears to be some sort of bell perhaps.  However, I am unable to figure out what kind and what the PDF is.  All series I generate from various "random" sources seem to yield similar results, but not exact ( of course ).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a typical question for the mathematical field of combinatorics. You may get better answers in the math stackexchange forum.

Comment: The reason I asked here is that this kind of test seems to be used primarily in terms of testing randomness of PRNGs, and I was hoping someone here has already solved this problem.   However, I did ask a similar ( more Math focused ) question based on your comment.  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp. Also consider posting this to codegolf. They love these kind of problems and will give you an implementation in less than 64byte:-)